# Creating a cookie inside a jax-rs endpoint

Tags: java, cookies, jax-rs, endpoint

I have a jax-rs endpoint. The purpose of the endpoint is to authorize a user. I need to login details inside a cookie. Below I have mentioned the related part of my code.

```
public Response authorize(@Context HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException {
     if (authnResult.isAuthenticated()) {
     //TODO create a cookie to maintain login state
                        Cookie authCookie = new Cookie(FrameworkConstants.COMMONAUTH_COOKIE, "test");
                        authCookie.setSecure(true);
                        authCookie.setHttpOnly(false);
                        authCookie.setMaxAge(5 * 60);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

This is my first time when creating cookies. I followed some tutorials. In these tutorials it has added the created cookie to the response. But inside the endpoint I can't access the response. So how can I create the cookie? Please advice me.

Updated code:

```
public Response authorize(@Context HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException {
    NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie("CookieName","CookieValue");
                    Response.ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok("Cool Stuff");
                    builder.cookie(cookie);
                    Response response=builder.build();
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
}
```

what I need to know is how to access the newly created cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [`javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/NewCookie.html). There are a bunch of different constructors, just go through the API docs.

Then you can add cookies through [`ResponseBuilder#cookie(NewCookie)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#cookie%28javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie...%29). So for example:

```
@GET
public Response getCookie() {
    NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie("Name", "Value", "path", "domain",
                                     "comment", 300, true, true);
    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok("Cool Stuff");
    builder.cookie(cookie);
    return builder.build();
}
```

---

#### UPDATE (with complete example)

```
@Path("cookie")
public class CookieResource {
    
    @GET
    public Response getCookie(@CookieParam("A-Cookie") String cookie) {
        Response response = null;
        if (cookie == null) {
            response = Response.ok("A-Cookie: Cookie #1")
                    .cookie(new NewCookie("A-Cookie", "Cookie #1"))
                    .build();
            return response;
        } else {
            String cookieNum = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("#") + 1);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(cookieNum);
            number++;
            String updatedCookie = "Cookie #" + number;
            response = Response.ok("A-Cookie: " + updatedCookie)
                    .cookie(new NewCookie("A-Cookie", updatedCookie))
                    .build();
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

After 38 requests, you can see the result. I used a Firefox plugin [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). You can see the sent cookie #37, and returned cookie #38

[image]

If you need help trying to access the cookie from the client (as suggested in your comment), that may be suitable for another question on SO. Maybe off topic for this discussion, as it will rely on another technology. If this is not what you are looking for, then maybe a better explanation of exactly what you are trying to accomplish would help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion peeskillet. I'll try it.

Comment: I followed the way that you suggested. I need to access the created cookie by using the  HttpServletRequest request which I pass to the method as a parameter. I tried to use 'request.getCookies()' but I could not access the newly created cookie. Please suggest me a way to do that thing also.

Comment: If you mean in the next request, you can just use `@CookieParam("...")` as the method parameter annotation, and it will inject the cookie value. Also what user agent are you using. It depends if the user agent will send the cookie back. If you're simply using a browser, it should work.

Comment: Yes I'm using a browser as the agent. I have updated the code. Please help me to access the cookie by providing a code snippet. Sorry for the unawareness.

Comment: Based on your code, I really have no idea what you are trying to do? You first need to access the resource once, the cookie will be sent to the client, then one the next request, the client should send the cookie back. One the first request there should be no cookie to get.

Comment: Actually I had to edit an existing endpoint which was not written by me. Inside that endpoint I need to create a cookie. Once I add the cookie I should have the ability to access that cookie using the browser. Once I added above code that you have mentioned will I be able to access the cookie in the browser.

Comment: See my **UPDATE**. Other than that I probably have no idea what exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe a better explanation would help. If you need help accessing the cookie with your front end client code, then maybe you should ask a different question on SO, as it would involve using your client technology, which IMO is off topic for this particular post

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll follow the things you have mentioned.